# send option selection via. jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some problems sending an id though jquery. 
I have a form select with some values, i want to "grap" the id when change option selection.

Output error: [object Object] !! :/

```
<select name="case_name" id="case_id">
            <option value="10009" >Case 1</option>
            <option value="10010" >Case 2</option>
            <option value="10011" >Case 3</option>
            </select>



    var PARAMS = { "case_id": 10009 }; 

$("#case_id").change(function() {  
    var CASE_ID = $(this).val();
    var PARAMS = { "case_id": CASE_ID };
    alert(CASE_ID);
});
```

Comment: the problem now is that PARAMS has to have an value, before selection. 

If i set default value to 100 it returns 100 everytime, i submit, also if i change my selection. 

if i debug with alert box, it shows the correct value :S i'm confused.

Comment: you're mixing the scopes. PARAMS is declared twice here, in different scopes (global and inside the anonymous function). Remove the var from `var PARAMS` inside the change callback. BTW, it's not a good idea to have global variables like this floating around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CASE_ID` is defined inside an anonymous function and is only valid inside this function. And inside the callback you can simply refer to the select box as `this`.

```
$("#case_id").change(function() {
    var CASE_ID = $(this).val();
});
```

Outside the anonymous function, it does not exist.

```
var PARAMS = { "case_id": CASE_ID };
```

Either modify the `change` callback to include the PARAMS object.

```
$("#case_id").change(function() {  
    var CASE_ID = $(this).val();
    var PARAMS = { "case_id": CASE_ID };

});
```

Or fetch the value again

```
var PARAMS = { "case_id": $("#case_id").val() };
```

Or maybe define a function that you pass the new selected value to:

```
function sendValue(value) {
    var PARAMS = { "case_id": value };
    // send the value somewhere
}

$("#case_id").change(function() {
    var CASE_ID = $(this).val();
    sendValue(CASE_ID);
});
```

Comment: I changed the top code, with some of yours. I still get som problems with it. (read my comment at the top) :)

Answer (score 3):

```
var CASE_ID = $("#case_id option:selected").val();
```